# sObjectField Class Methods getLabel()

Tags: apex, label, describes

The `SObjectField` class has a `getDescribe()` method. Does anyone know of a creative way to get the field label for use in Apex? There does not seem to be a `getLabel()` method per [the official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm).

Comment: Please reference [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned, you need to call `getDescribe()`, which returns a **[`DescribeFieldResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)**.

```
SObjectField field = Opportunity.AccountId;
DescribeFieldResult describe = field.getDescribe();
String label = describe.getLabel();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get a field's label using the following one-liner:

```
String label = Account.Name.getDescribe().getLabel();
System.debug(label); //prints 'Account Name'
```